# Root The Box - easy CTF framework

Tags: authentication

I am planning to host a CTF contest in a few months at my local university. While searching for some hints I met this wonderful tool called Root The Box.

It basically gives you all you need to host a CTF, including scoreboard, bots, flags and integrates all boxes and databases. Since it is designed for begginers, it should be no hard to use.

Well, I followed the wiki [2](https://github.com/moloch--/RootTheBox/wiki) and everything seemed to be working, until I tried to authenticate. It keeps telling me the game has not started yet.

[image]

Everything is set to localhost, including server and database (just want to try it first).

Still, it seems to be pretty interesting. Has anyone ever tried it? Any hints on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It has been a while since I last tried using it but I believe you need to log in using the admin account you set up during installation to start the game before you can log in as a contestant. My memory may be a bit fuzzy though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working a little after asking here (shame on me). Root The Box is configured to devel mode by default. So, after configuring your files you have to set it to production mode.

```
./rootthebox.py --setup=prod
```

And yes, you do have to be an admin user so you can start the game after loggin into your account. Damn, I lost so much time with it! Hope it can help someone someday.